# Is there a method using which i can identify if a particular block at LLC is a data block or an instruction block in champsim simulator

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I am using champsim to simulate the paper with title "Improving lifetime of NVM caches using logical partitioning" in that paper they partitioned the ways into data and instruction ways logically and then they are swapping between them to maintain the wear leveling but i am not getting how can i know that if the block is an instruction or a data way at LLC using champsim simulator.

I tried printing the `writeback_packet.is_data` but i showed some weird output and when i printed `writeback_packet.instruction` it printed '/00', also when i am printing data of a block most of the times it is printing 0 and sometimes a number.